# Como transformar um vetor com strings(lista) em um vetor números inteiros no Python?

Tags: python, array, string, lista, split

Eu sou nova em programação python. Me deparei hoje com o desafio de pegar um vetor(ex:V1== ['MESA 11 22 33 44 ']) em que todos os seus elementos estão em formato string (como se fossem uma só, apenas separados por espaço). A questão é separar esse vetor para que fique nesse formato: V1==['MESA', 1, 2, 3, 4], onde eu mantenho a palavra MESA como string e os demais números eu converto para inteiro.
Tentei da seguinte maneira: primeiro tentei transformar cada string com o split() em um índice.

```
for i, vetor in enumerate(V1):
    V1[i].append(vetor[i].split())
print(V1)
```

Após isso, criei outro vetor(V2) para receber o V1 convertido para int. Assim, criei um IF para que se na posição atual estiver a palavra "MESA", ele adicionar o conteúdo do V1 no V2 sem precisar converter para int, e se for diferente disso, o índice será convertido para um número em, formato int.

```
V2=[]
for i in range(len(V1)):
    if V1[i] == 'MESA':
        V2[i]= V1[i]
    else:
        V2[i].append((int(V1[i]))
 print(V2)
```

Eu não sei se meu problema está na minha lógica, mas não consigo acertar a sintaxe disso. Desde já agradeço se alguém puder ajudar!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solução em uma linha:

```py
V2=[round(int(k)/11) if k.isdigit() else k for k in V1[0].strip().split(" ")]
```

Usei list comprehension para criar a nova lista. O condicional verifica se a substring é um digito (`is_digit()`), se não for, ele deixa o elemento como está.

O `strip` apenas remove os espaços antes e depois da string.

Leia sobre list comprehension na [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). Pode te ajudar em situações similares.

Comment: o resultado esperado pelo usuário é `['MESA', 1, 2, 3, 4]`. Para  obtermos este resultado devemos utilizar `round(int(k) / 11)` em vez de `int(k)`.

Comment: Obrigado @Solkarped . Falta de atenção minha. Vou corrigir

Comment: Obrigada de verdade, ajudou muito hehe. Eu estava extremamente confusa quanto a isso, agora compreendo e lerei o material!

Comment: Imagina. Se esta resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida.

Comment: Apenas mais uma dúvida, se não for incomodar. Se o número for negativo, por exemplo, eu teria de fazer uma função com try e ecxept para que eu possa converte-los? Visto que isdigit() não considera o sinal "-"

Comment: Nesse caso, basta substituir o condicional por `k.replace("-","").isdigit()`